# Serial Port conflicts with threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, serial-port

This is my simplified class which is used to detect problem in my full program:

**SimpleThread.h**

```
class SimpleThread {
public:

    SimpleThread();
    ~SimpleThread();

    void startThread();
    void threadFn();

private:

    SerialPort mySerial;

    std::thread myThread;
    int count;
    std::mutex myMutex;
};
```

**SimpleThread.cpp**

```
SimpleThread::SimpleThread(): mySerial("/dev/ttyACM0") {
    count = 0;
    mySerial.Open(//Here correct params//);
}

SimpleThread::~SimpleThread() {}

void SimpleThread::threadFn() {

    char cp;

    while (true) {
        cp = mySerial.ReadByte(0);
        std::cout << count++ << " " << cp << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void SimpleThread::startThread() {
    myThread = std::thread(&SimpleThread::threadFn, this);
    myThread.detach();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {

    SimpleThread thr;
    thr.startThread();

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Waiting 5 seconds" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }
}
```

The main idea of my example: I am using class member function as thread function to read data from opened serial port. There are no problems in using this class without reading from serial: main loop prints message every 5 seconds while thread loop (function inside class) prints 5 numbers.

Now I want to implement reading from serial port while my main loop is going to do something else. To read/write in serial I took [this](http://libserial.sourceforge.net/doxygen/_serial_port_8h-source.html) not so up-to-date serial library.

In this case class starts to work unexpected for me: main loop (which should show message every 5 seconds) shows its message faster then thread loop (about 40 times while 1 second). This code works wrong cause main loop prints message 40 times at 1 second (after read byte) despite sleep function.

So my question is: where is the root of my problem? Should I use another serial library or there are some features connected with interruptions which I dont know about?

**Edit:** If I use next loop for reading with checking if data is available, the main loop prints after every read byte. Looks like reading byte in thread loop interrupts main loop and cancels sleeping.

```
if ( mySerial.IsDataAvailable() ) {
    cp = mySerial.ReadByte(0);
    std::cout << count++ << " " << cp << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

**Edit 2:** Moreover, I tested just opening the Serial but without reading from Serial in loop (with changed pause in thread loop on two seconds)

```
if ( mySerial.IsDataAvailable() ) {
    std::cout << count++ << " " << cp << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}
```

In this case main loop prints every one second. There is no problem only if Serial port is not opened.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  Is the code that you have showed to us the code that does what you expect? or is it the code that does _not_ do what you expect?

Comment: @RustyX Sorry for my not so pure english, I try to do my best. Main loop printed about 40 times at second after every read byte.

Comment: @jameslarge Sorry for my not so pure english too. This code does not do what I expect cause main loop prints message about 40 times every second despite sleep function. I would edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libserial](https://github.com/crayzeewulf/libserial) uses asynchronous I/O which is based on signals (`SIGIO` to be precise) and there was a bug in GCC 5 ([#66803](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66803)) in which `std::this_thread::sleep_for` was interrupted by signals. It has been fixed in GCC 6.

The possible solutions are:

- Upgrade your compiler to GCC 6+ or clang/LLVM.
- Use a workaround like the one mentioned in the bug [66803](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66803#c3) or try `sleep_until`:

  ```
  auto wakeup_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);
  std::this_thread::sleep_until(wakeup_time);
  ```
- Use blocking I/O (I believe you can simply open the serial device as a file and read from it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have already change my code with simple reading by byte without this library and it workes. So this is definetely bug in libserial and you have confirmed my suggestion. Thank you again for help and understanding!